# Strtok for every line and search a word in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, strtok, adjacency-list

1. I open the input file
2. I read it
3. Store an 2D array
4. split into tokens
5. firslt strtok for "\n"  and store it
6. secondly strtok for ":" ignore it
7. and then strtok for "," and store it
8. I want to search a word for every single line (which I stored it step 5)
9. For searching I use strstr but I can't do it.

I add my input file and code .

```
int
main ()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("C:\\input.txt", "r");
  char *name[10][10];
  char row[100];
  char *token, *tkn, *tk;
  int h = 0, f = 0, l = 0;
  for (h = 0; h < 9; h++)
    {
      for (f = 0; f < 9; f++)
        name[h][f] = NULL;
    }
  while (fgets (row, sizeof (row), fp))
    {
      token = strtok (row, "\n");
      name[l][0] = strdup (token);
      //printf("%s",name[l][0]);
      tkn = strtok (token, ":");
      tk = strtok (tkn, ",");
      isim[l][1] = strdup (tk);
      if (strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 1][0]) == 0
          || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 2][0]) == 0
          || strstr (name[l][1], name[l + 3][0]) == 0)
        {

        }
      l++;
    }
  fclose (fp);
}
```

I want to insert a linked list wth this function.

```
struct AdjListNode{
char *courseName;
char *studentName;

struct AdjList *head;
struct AdjListNode *nextPtr;};
typedef struct AdjListNode node;
typedef struct AdjListNode* nodePtr;
typedef struct AdjListNode** nodePtrPtr;



nodePtr insertVertex(nodePtrPtr header,char *studentName,char *courseName){
nodePtr newNode, temp, prev;
// create node to insert and assign values to its fields
//newNode=createAdjListNode(studentName,courseName);
newNode=malloc(sizeof(node));
newNode->studentName=studentName;
newNode->courseName=courseName;
newNode->nextPtr=NULL;
// if LL empty
if (*header == NULL)
    *header=newNode;
// if LL not empty
else {
    temp=*header;
    while (temp != NULL && (strcmp(temp->courseName,newNode->courseName)<0)) {
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->nextPtr;
    }
    while (temp!=NULL && (strcmp(temp->courseName,newNode->courseName)==0)) {
        printf("\n existent key \n");
        return temp;
    }
    // insert node in a sorted fashion
    if (temp!=NULL)
        newNode->nextPtr=temp;
    // if value to insert is the least in LL then have header point to node
    if (temp==*header)
        *header=newNode;
    // otherwise insert node in correct position
    else
        prev->nextPtr=newNode;
    }
    return newNode;}
```

My input.txt file:

```
George    :Math1,History2,Math2
ELizabeth :Math2,Germany1,spanish1
Adam      :Germany1,History2,Math1
```

I want to create a graph with lecture names and I want to use adjancecy list. For adjancecy list I need the connection of two lectures but I'm stuck with this step. How can I search whole line and then store an array. For example I search Math1 . it is in 2 lines .And then I want to create an adj list Math1 ->History2->Math2->Germany1 for Math1 .Please help me

Comment: Fill the array first and then build your list, outside the while loop. Also, remember to free up the memory allocated by strdup at the end of your program. Check for NULL pointers while building the list - strstr may crash if you supply a NULL argument

Comment: Ok but I didn't do this . How ?@BugKiller

Comment: Note: As `token = strtok (row, "\n")` and `tkn = strtok (token, ":");` may return a `NULL`, defensive coding would account for that.

Comment: Your definition of connectivity within the graph wasn't clear, but I'm sure you can build it by running a for loop over the array elements. Create a linked list for each token you find and add elements to the list

Comment: I try. They don't return NULL . @chux Do you know answer for question ,?

Comment: I want to create a graph with lessons . I write insert method I insert them a linked list but I need connection for a lecture . for example Math1's neighbours are History2,Math2,Germany1 and for example Math2's neighbours are Math1,History2,Germany1,Spanish1 @BugKiller

Comment: and now I add my insert function in this question .I edit the question with insert function. Please help me @BugKiller

Comment: I add my insert function @BugKiller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store an array using strtok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649985/store-an-array-using-strtok)