# Store an array using strtok

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error, strtok

```
int main (){

FILE *file = fopen ( "C:\\input.txt", "r" );
int i=0, j=0, k=0;

char *result[10][10];   
char line[100];    
char *value;
char *res[100][100];

for(i=0; i<=9; i++){         
    for(j=0;j<=9;j++){
        result[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
    char *array=strtok(line,"\n");
    res[0][0]=strdup(array);  

    printf("\n\n\n %s RES \n",res[0][0]);
    array=strtok(array,"\n");
    res[0][1]=strdup(array);

    printf("\n\n\n %s RES \n",res[0][1]);
    array=strtok(line,"\n");
    res[0][2]=strdup(array);
}
```

I want to store an array in a txt file line by line. There are `3` rows in my input file. I want every line is stored by in an array. How can I do that ? this is always store first element.

my input file :

```
George    :Math1,History2,Math2
ELizabeth :Math2,Germany1,spanish1
Adam      :Germany1,History2,Math1
```

Comment: This is always store in res[][] same thin : the first line always

Comment: I want to store every line in my input file in an array. For example I want to res[0][0] = "George    :Math1,History2,Math2" , res[0][1]=ELizabeth :Math2,Germany1,spanish1 and res[0][2]=Adam      :Germany1,History2,Math1 @giorgim

Comment: What exactly is the idea of passing `"\n"` to `strtok()`? For your reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Comment: If I don2t use *res[][] , there is an error for strtok @giorgim

Comment: the exactly idea is strtok("\n") ---> splint into tokens for every line @alk I think for spliting every line .

Comment: how can I split every line in an niput file using strtok ? @alk

Comment: Read line by line using `fgets()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). Parse each line using `strtok(line, " :,")`.

Comment: no it doesn't work  ---> strtok(line, " :,") @alk

Comment: Please RTFM to `strtok()`! As linked by my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading those three lines into array why don't you use something as simple as this:

```
 char res[100][100];
 int i =0;
 while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
        strcpy(&res[i][0],line);
        printf("%s \n",&res[i][0]);
        i++;
 }
```